# "There is [no way] 'of proving'/'to prove' that he was *wrong*/*right*"

Tags: difference, gerunds, infinitives

> 1.A There is [no way] ***to prove*** that he was *wrong*.
>
> 1.B There is [no way] ***of proving*** that he was *wrong*.
>
> 2.A There is [no way] ***to prove*** that he was *right*.
>
> 2.B There is [no way] ***of proving*** that he was *right*.

Are "of proving" and "to prove" completely interchangeable? If not, is there a correlation betwen these phrases and the words "wrong" and "right"? If yes, why are 1.B and 2.B cases wrong if one drops the phrase "no way"?

Answer (score 4):

All four sentences are grammatically incorrect if *no way* is dropped.

One **can** say:

> *This* **{goes / is} to prove** that he was {right / wrong}".

In this case, the two phrases *to prove* and *of proving* seem to me to be fungible. They're just a style preference.

Have you seen any documents that say *There is to prove that he was {right / wrong}*? Please provide a link.

Comment: +1 However, all four are correct when *no way* is changed to *a way*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, but the OP didn't suggest that possibility. :-)

Comment: Then that is a deficiency on  his part which should be remedied. Perhaps he doesn't know of the possibility and would be happy to be informed of it. :)

Comment: Bill, on Internet there are several instances of "there is to prove that," among which it seems interesting the following (telegraph.co.uk) "... how much evidence there is to prove that 9/11 was indeed an attack planned and carried out by AQ." However there are others, also on The New York Times.

Comment: ... "... the supposition that Foster's death was a homicide than there is to prove that Nicole Brown Simpson ..." one can read on The New York Times.

Comment: ... in other words, it doesn't seem so rare to find that expression.

Comment: @Carlo The NYT examples don't begin sentences; yours do.  By the way, it would be easier to talk about these examples with either complete sentences or links to where complete sentences can be found.

Comment: @Carlo: Two problems with your NYT examples. First, as snailplane points out, they are not complete sentences, merely snippets & structurally (syntactically) different from your four example sentences. Second, the NYT is a pay-to-read site after the first 10 articles in any given 30-day period from an initial click on a NYT article, so please copy & paste the full sentence (plus the previous one or two, if possible or relevant).

Comment: @Carlo_R.  The example you give is clearly syntactically different, as Bill says: it is a relative clause with a 'null-relativizer': *evidence [which] there is to prove that ...* Translated into your structure this would be *There is evidence to prove that ...* (or *There is evidence proving that ...*).

Comment: Also grammatically correct would be to finish the phrases with ... (to prove|of proving) (him|her|them|...) (right|wrong|[in]correct).

Answer (score 3):

In your base sentence, *There is no way*, the noun ***way*** is what determines what constructions may follow. ***Way*** takes (as we used to put it—today the technical term is *licenses*) the following constructions with the sense *[Subject] can prove X*

> **Non-finite clauses**
>    - a way ***to prove X***
>    - a way ***of proving X***
>    - a way ***for Subject to prove X***
>
> **Finite clauses**
>    - a way ***(that/in which) Subject can prove X***
>    - a way ***(that/in which) X can be proven***

This is true whether your base sentence is *There is no way* or *There is a way* or *There may be a way* or *There are many ways* or any other variation on this theme: *way* determines what constructions are permissible.

But when you drop *no way* you change the entire structure of the sentence. The construction *There is*, by itself, can only take a noun phrase as its complement. None of these constructions will work.

The apparent counter-examples you cite belong to different structures:

> To someone infected by the conspiracy theory virus it doesn't matter how much evidence there is to prove that 9/11 was indeed an attack ... *Once you unpack the relative clause, the relevant piece of the sentence boils down to **There is evidence to prove that X**.*
>
> There is less evidence to support the supposition that Foster's death was a homicide than there is to prove that Nicole Brown Simpson was ... *Again, after unpacking, the relevant piece of the sentence boils down to **There is more evidence to prove that X**.*

***Evidence*** performs the same role in both of these as ***way*** in your sentence, governing what constructions are permissible.